# Uniqueness of solution to ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow [0,+\infty)$ is smooth, 1-periodic with
\begin{equation*}
\min_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) = 0.
\end{equation*}
I consider the following ODE:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\dot{\eta}(s) &= \Phi(f(\eta(s))), \qquad\text{for}\qquad s>0,\\
\eta(0) &= 0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $\Phi: [0,\infty)\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ is strictly increasing, smooth on $(0,+\infty)$ with $\Phi(0) = 0$.

Is it true that if $f(0) = 0$ then the unique solution is $\eta(s)\equiv 0$? I am thinking about some sort of nonlinear Gronwall's inequality to show this but haven't be successful yet.

Comment: Try to reproduce the behavior of $\dot y=\sqrt{|y|}$, $f(x)=\sin^2(\pi x)$ and $Φ(u)=\sqrt[4]{u}$ should work.

Comment: The uniqueness of the zero solution of the IVP is determined by the **local** behavior of $\Phi \circ f$ at zero. The only relevance of periodicity of $f$ I can think of is that $f'(0)=0$. It seems that $f(x)=1-\cos(2\pi x)$ and $\Phi(y)=\sqrt[4]{y}$ could be a counterexample.